# Check if array values are between two values of another array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I have two arrays.  One step wise:

```
steps = np.arange(0, 50, 2.5)
vect = np.random.normal(50, 5.6, 100)
index = [x for x in np.arange(len(a))]
```

I want to check if each element of `vect` is *in between* the elements of a pair of `steps`.  For example, if `vect[0]` is between elements `steps[0]` and `steps[1]`, it'd return `True`, else `False`.  so each item of `vect` will be checked against ALL the items in `steps` in pairs, if that makes sense.  I was thinking something like this:

```
for x in index:
    for y in vect:
        print(steps[x] <= y <= steps[x+1])
```

This obviously doesn't work.  Plus, I need a separate list for each `step` pair (they will actually be columns in a dataframe).  Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You mention DataFrame. Are you using pandas?

Comment: yes I am.  i know how to get it into a dataframe. i just don't know about the logic and the iteration to check each element of the array against a pair of elements in another array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ufunc.outer` like so:

```
steps = np.arange(0, 22.5, 2.5)
vect = np.random.normal(10, 5.0, 10)

np.less.outer(vect,steps[1:]) & np.greater_equal.outer(vect,steps[:-1])
```

Sample output:

```
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False]])
```

Or as DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame(np.less.outer(vect,steps[1:]) & np.greater_equal.outer(vect,steps[:-1]), columns=[f"{steps[i]:.1f}-{steps[i+1]:.1f}" for i in range(len(steps)-1)])
```

Output:

```
   0.0-2.5  2.5-5.0  5.0-7.5  7.5-10.0  10.0-12.5  12.5-15.0  15.0-17.5  17.5-20.0
0    False    False    False     False      False      False       True      False
1    False    False    False     False       True      False      False      False
2    False     True    False     False      False      False      False      False
3    False    False    False      True      False      False      False      False
4    False    False    False      True      False      False      False      False
5    False    False    False     False       True      False      False      False
6    False    False    False     False      False      False      False       True
7    False    False    False      True      False      False      False      False
8    False    False     True     False      False      False      False      False
9    False    False    False      True      False      False      False      False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
steps = np.arange(0, 50, 2.5)
vect = np.random.normal(50, 5.6, 100)
indexes = {}
for index, value in enumerate(steps):
    for value in vect:
        if index < len(steps)-1:
            if steps[index] < value < steps[index+1]:
                indexes[value] = (index, index+1)
```

at the end you will get a dictionary like where key is value in vect and value is interval endpoints from steps, as a tuple. Like this :

```
  <class 'dict'>: {39.99995073703162: (15, 16), 
                   39.154971948950724: (15, 16), 
                   39.734181390461416: (15, 16)
                   44,5: (17, 18)}
```

Is this what you need ?

With a bit of refactoring you can do it even smaller using python specific stuff

Using Lambda functions is even much more simple. https://thispointer.com/pandas-apply-apply-a-function-to-each-row-column-in-dataframe/

Using lambdas, the first for is impolitely executed and the second for can be written in one line.